# what is the effective way to compare strings?

Tags: c, unit-testing

I am writing the different set of strings generated by a piece of software into a text file. I want to write a test so that it compares the generated and written text for any possible error!

What is the effective way to do such test?

Answer (score 1):

To compare two strings in C programming, you have to ask the user to enter the two strings and start comparing using the function `strcmp()`.

If it will return 0, then both strings are equal.

If it will not return 0, then both strings are not be equal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method to compare C strings is the `strcmp()` function declared in `<string.h>`.

There are a few special cases where more efficient solutions can be sought:

- if the strings have a known length: `memcmp()` can be used and might perform better as it does not need to test for end of strings.
- if only equality is to be tested, the extra work performed by `strcmp()` to compute the  relative lexicographical order of the strings could be avoided, but `strcmp()` is usually implemented very efficiently, so it is unlikely you get any improvement by handcoding an alternative in C.